# programmatically know from which connector the request made in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, ajp

I have multiple connectors configured in tomcat 8.5.23 (http, https and ajp). Is there any way to know programmatically from which connector the request is coming from. One detection i can do is based on the port but wanted to know is there any easier way to know the connector type programmatically.

Thanks.

Comment: "One detection i can do is based on the port" It'd be worth showing your code for this to demonstrate you've actually made an effort.

Comment: What do you really want to know, here? Usually, the identity of the connector itself is pretty useless. Are you after some other specific piece of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your request is an instance of `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` you can cast it and call the `getConnector` method to get the associated connector.